# SQL server pivot table for time keeping

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have a time keeping table that records the following data:

```
+----------------+-------------------------+-------+
| TK_EMPLOYEE_ID |       TK_DATETIME       | TK_ID |
+----------------+-------------------------+-------+
|            101 | 2013-09-30 08:01:54.000 |     1 |
|            101 | 2013-09-30 12:02:16.000 |     2 |
|            101 | 2013-09-30 12:30:12.000 |     3 |
|            101 | 2013-09-30 16:31:02.000 |     4 |
|            101 | 2013-10-01 08:33:59.000 |     5 |
|            101 | 2013-10-01 12:05:59.000 |     6 |
|            101 | 2013-10-01 12:30:29.000 |     7 |
|            101 | 2013-10-01 16:40:48.000 |     8 |
|            102 | 2013-10-01 08:00:48.000 |     9 |
|            102 | 2013-10-01 12:00:48.000 |     10|
+----------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

The clock entries are taken so that the odd scans are "CLOCK IN" and the even are "CLOCK OUT". So in the table above we can see that the employee clocked in at 8:01am, clocked out at 12:02; clocked back in from lunch at 12:30 and left work and 16:31.

How could I format display this in a SQL pivot table to display something like the following detailing entries for each day of the week?

```
EMPID        | Mon                    | Tue                         | Wed 
101          | 8:01 - 12:02 (4:01)    | 08:33 - 12:05 (03:32)       | etc
             | 12:30- 16:31 (4:01)    | 12:30 - 16:40 (04:10        |

102          | 8:00- 12:00 (4:00)
```

The time difference between the two times is shown in brackets.

I plan on using SSRS to display the results.